# Get current value of search input on SharePoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Would like to get a pure Javascript solution for my situation.

My HTML and JS is as follows. But the HTML can't be manipulated unfortunately as its on SP.

```js
function getCurrentValue() {
  var searchQuery = document.getElementById("SearchBox").children[0].children[0].value;
  console.log(searchQuery);
}
```

```html
<div id="SearchBox">
  <div id"randomGeneratedId">
    <input type="text" value="Search..." id="anotherRandomGeneratedId"/>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Run!" onClick="getCurrentValue();">
```

The JS above works in the snippet here but on my page it returns the default value of the input ie. "Search..."

FYI its running on SharePoint 2013. I should note that I managed to get it to work when getElementId("anotherRandomGeneratedId") but that require writing a custom script for every page.

Comment: Do you mean it returns the default value after you change the text in the input? If so, I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes, that's what i mean. Thanks, I'll move this to the SharePoint stack exchange then.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try to modify `getCurrentValue()` to:

```
function getCurrentValue() {
    var searchQuery = document.querySelector("#SearchBox input").value;
    console.log(searchQuery);
}
```